# TableView not updating after deleting an entry in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an application that uses the realtime data from Firebase. Whenever I add an entry to the database, it is displayed on the tableView, however, when I delete something from the database (manually delete it from Firebase), it is not refreshed on the application and the tableView doesn't refresh.

Here's my code for the refreshing and the `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` methods.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("post-items")
    startObservingDB()

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    startObservingDB()
}

func startObservingDB(){

    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var newPost = [Post]()

        for post in snapshot.children{
            let postObject = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newPost.append(postObject)
        }

        self.posts = newPost
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

What am I missing? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First you should check the `self.posts` before and after you delete entry.

Comment: @nynohu can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I mean did you check the dataSource has changed or not? In that case i guess dataSource is self.posts, isn't it

Comment: @nynohu yes that contains the posts data. I checked and printed it out. It has the content. When I go to write a post, and decide to cancel, the tableView refreshes and stops showing the deleted posts. What I'm trying to do is to get the tableView to refresh as they get deleted.

Comment: So when you delete an entry, has `dbRef.observeSingleEvent` been called? I think the problem is when you deleted an entry, now there is no notification was observed.

Comment: @nynohu I went over the code and changed the method to `dbRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in` it works good now. Thanks man. Write your comment as an answer to mark is as selected answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't work with FireBase and Swift but you can refer:
  [[[_ref child:@"users"] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    // Update data and reload tableView
  } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
  }];

Comment: @nynohu I changed the method that just checks for all event types. Your comment helped me out a lot. Just write your comment as an answer to mark is as selected answer if you want to.

Comment: That's ok, no need to write as an answer. Cheers.

Comment: When you observe a value by calling `observeSingleEvent`, you will get the value of the node **once**. So when you later delete a node, your callback will not be invoked. I'm going to vote this as off-topic/typo, since it's unlikely that anyone in the same situation will find this question.

Comment: @The answer on the comments very helpful for me :) Cheers